# Python selenium does not find elements on web page, although they are clearly visible

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to scrape a web directory, just for my scraping training. But it's weird, it finds featured links without a problem, while it does not find regular links.
This is the code that doesn't find the links:

```
for page in range(1,5):
try:
    driver.get("https://www.jasminedirectory.com/business-marketing/page,{}.html".format(page))
    print(driver.current_url)
    time.sleep(5)

    try:
        articles = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="entryNorm"]')


        data = []
        for article in articles:

            title = article.find_element_by_xpath('.//a[@class="entryNorm9"]').text
```

What to do here? Pls help.
Thanks!

Comment: have you tried looking for that element? by name, or full xpath or id? mind you that some web pages have "layers" of ads or other feature that could make an object "not visiable" by the selenium driver...  please try to look for that element using its name or id

Comment: `try` needs to have an except clause, you got that?

Comment: I do have an except clause, of course, just didn't paste that part of the code:)

Answer (score 0):

So this works:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3


from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time

options = Options()
# options.headless = True

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options,service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))


for page in range(1,5):
    driver.get("https://www.jasminedirectory.com/business-marketing/page,{}.html".format(page))
    print(driver.current_url)
    time.sleep(5)

#updated classes
    articles = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="entryNorm"]')


    data = []
    for article in articles:

        title = article.find_element(By.XPATH, './/div[@class="entryNorm9"]').text
        desc = article.find_element(By.XPATH, './/div[@class="entryNorm9"]').text
        link = article.find_element(By.XPATH, './/div[@class="lnkurl"]').text
        
        print(title, desc, link)
```

A couple of things that I changed:

- Found elements that actually exist in the page.
- Changed the articles to `find.elements` plural so it's iterable.
- Changed the syntax for `XPATH`.
- Removed `try` cause they require an `except` clause.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not looking for featured links, only standard ones, as stated in the code (div class entryNorm). Please find the first link on this url for reference hxxps://www.jasminedirectory.com/business-marketing/page,3.html

Comment: @natalie22 I updated the code to look for those classes. It feels I am doing your homework though. You could have simply changed the class names. The answer was perfectly adequate as should be marked correct. Enjoy scraping <3

Comment: Sorry, but that was exactly what I was talking about; I did change these classes, but it just skips each page (3,4.), because it does not find them. Weird, ha?

Comment: `const entries = document.querySelectorAll('.entryNorm')` it gave me 15 entries on page 3. Using JS and the browser window. Part of the scraping is to inspect.